# How to Check if Current Post is the First or Last Post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I checked Google and went through the Wordpress template tags but I still can't figure this out - in the single.php template file, which is the one used to display a specific post, how do I check whether this post is the most recent one OR the oldest post? Essentially I need to know whether this is first or last post out of all my posts.

Comment: I answered my own question just now:


get_next_post, and get_previous_post will return a blank value if there is no next or previous post...

Comment: Consider filling out the answer section and marking your answer as accepted. You're allowed to do that with answers to your own questions, and it makes it more obvious for new users that the question has been answered.

Comment: I see the button now. I was expecting the form as on a blog.. I'll do that right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to check for their existence and don't need the link, you should use [`get_previous_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post) and [`get_next_post`.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post) They don't apply unnecessary formatting that you would ignore if you just use it in an `if` test. You can still get a link from the post object it returns by passing it to [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink).

Comment: Thank you.. however as you can see above under my comments, I figured it out 2 minutes after I wrote the question! I just couldn't find the function soon enough. I'll give you credit anyway tho!